# When running this code, it doesn't actually replace the strings... Why? Also, will making this be practical?

Tags: python

Sorry for the messy code. I didn't have time really. I'm new and just been experimenting. I just wanna know why the strings aren't replaced.
As you can see, the "b64ed" and "final_product" are the same...

Sorry in advance. I'm stupid xD

```
import base64;
import time;
import os;
import random;
import string;
import Crypto
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto import Random
import ast


enc_method = input("Would you like to manually input the text or load a .txt file? \n Press 1 for manual or 2 for importing: \n");


if enc_method == "1":
    filename = input("Enter the filename.txt: ");
    print("Importing String.... \n")
    with open(filename) as fn:
        toEnc_string = fn.read();
    print("String imported!");
    print(toEnc_string)

elif enc_method == "2":
    toEnc_string = input("Paste or Type the string you want to encrypt: \n");

else:
    print("For fucks sake...")


def oneS():
    return time.sleep(1)


def clearScreen():
    print("Clearing screen in 5...")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("4...")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("3...")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("2...")
    time.sleep(1)
    os.system("clear")

clearScreen()

def randomString(lenOfThatshit):
    letters = string.ascii_letters
    return ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(lenOfThatshit))

def bs64e(x):
    rummed = x.encode("utf-8")
    encoded = base64.b64encode(rummed)
    return encoded

print("You will now be asked to chose random Characters about 10 times. Choose differently each time.")
rs1 = input("Choose 6 random letters without spaces. Dont repeat: ")
rs2 = randomString(len(rs1))
#rs2 = input("Choose 6 more random letter without spaces. Dont repeat: ")

randStr = list(rs1)
randStr2 = list(rs2)

b64ed = str(bs64e(toEnc_string))

for i in range(6):
    final_product = b64ed.replace(str(randStr[i]) , str(randStr2[i]))
    print(str(randStr[i]) + "to " + str(randStr2[i]))

passes = open("the special random characters.txt", "w")
amount_written = passes.write(str(randStr) + "\n" + str(randStr2))

print(b64ed)
print("\n")
print(len(b64ed))
print("\n")
print(final_product)
print("\n")
print(len(final_product))
#print("Number of bytes written : " + str(amount_written))

passes.close()
```

Again, the code is really messy, I know. And there are many imports unused still. Forgive me. Also I will take any ideas.

Comment: What are you even trying to do here? Please provide some explanation with the code so that we can make sense of it!

Comment: Oh.. I thought it was obvious.
I am encoding a message in base64 and then replacing random characters with other characters.

Comment: Nothing is obvious mate! The code is honestly very unreadable!

Comment: Update the question please!

Comment: This line: 
`
b64ed = str(bs64e(toEnc_string))

for i in range(6):
    final_product = b64ed.replace(str(randStr[i]) , str(randStr2[i]))
    print(str(randStr[i]) + "to " + str(randStr2[i]))
`
Is what is messing up I think. Why isn't it replacing the characters?

Comment: What should `final_product` and `b64ed` look like, can you share an example, also what is the code supposed to do?

Comment: What do you mean man? What should it look like? I don't know what you're trying to do here. That's what it's supposed to look like. `b64ed` is supposed to contain the encoded message in string format and `final_product` is supposed to have the final result after replacing the characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a logical error there, always replacing chars in the `b64ed` string, so only the last of the replacement characters could actually be replaced. So you would see changes only if `b64ed` happened to contain the `randStr[5]` character, otherwise `final_product` would just be the exact same as `b64ed`.

Part of your code should look like this:

```
final_product = b64ed
for i in range(6):
    final_product = final_product.replace(str(randStr[i]) , str(randStr2[i]))
    print(str(randStr[i]) + " to " + str(randStr2[i]))
```

Comment: Yes I know. But try running the code yourself and see that it doesn't change anything anywhere

Comment: Oooooo. It's working. Also, you know how a base64 encoded message contains uppercase and lowercase, both. Is it possible to actually randomize the cases on these inputted characters in `rs1` ?

Comment: @UnknownUsername base64 char set is `ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwx yz0123456789+/` and `=` for the filler, that's why it can contain both lower and upper case characters. I don't understand your last sentence.

Comment: How can I randomize the cases in my input in `rs1` ?

Comment: @UnkownUsername I'm not sure what you mean, I'd advice you to edit your code and ask a new question with that :)

Comment: Oh ok. I'll do that. But thank you so much for your time. I really appreciate it.